# In a stored procedure if value is empty space or Nil change that value to others :SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure and I want to replace the column value in case if its empty string or Nil as written than those values should be changed to "others". I tried the replace function, but that did not fit with there. The values I get them in a dropdownlist

```
if(@Type='2')
Begin
    select distinct APlan.FlightNumber
    from tblArrivalPlan APlan
    where (Status=5 or Status=7 or Status=68)

    --select replace (APlan.FlightNumber,'004','JackSparrow') 
    --from tblArrivalPlan APlan
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CASE` to change `'', 'Nil', NULL` => `'others'`, rest values will have their original values:

```
if(@Type='2')
Begin
  select distinct 
     CASE WHEN APlan.FlightNumber IS NULL 
               OR APlan.FlightNumber IN ('', 'Nil') THEN 'others'
          ELSE APlan.FlightNumber
     END AS FlightNumber
  from tblArrivalPlan APlan
  where (Status=5 or Status=7 or Status=68)
end
```

Comment: I also have this value can not fit it their too 'OR APlan.FlightNumber='Nil' THEN 'others''

Comment: sorry to disturb you again: in case if there are 15 places where its ''empty string will the other be shown on those 15 places too, or we can show them just one

Comment: @user3515453 If you have more columns you probalby need to show them all using multiple `CASE WHEN`...

Comment: no not multi columns in same column 15 values , as it now I've tried yours it shows only single 'others' which is good, please confirm

Comment: @user3515453 If you have 15 values then only `'', 'NIL', NULL` will be changed to `Others` rest will have their original value.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be `NULLIF + (ISNULL or COALESCE)`

```
select distinct coalesce(NULLIF(NULLIF(APlan.FlightNumber,''),'Nil'),'Others')
from tblArrivalPlan APlan
where Status in (5, 7, 68)
```

Also instead of Multiple `OR` condition use single `IN` clause

Comment: I also have to change other column values in it to for example I've 'Nil' I want to change that one too to 'others' how can i do that in it too